# Changing the speed of boxes being created in the middle of happening (DOM "change" Events related)

Tags: javascript, html, css, setinterval, dom-events

I would like to change the speed of boxes being created anytime even in the midst of boxes being created. So far I have 4 buttons that work -- a button that generates random size/color boxes, a button that increments the size of the box, a button that resets the function, and a button that automatically creates based on the speed (milliseconds) of input value. As you can see, the speed changes every time I put a new value. Aforementioned, what I want to achieve is changing the speed freely without having to refresh the browser. I have started with Change function but got stuck there. Thank you for reading.

```js
let num = 0;
var dispDiv = document.getElementById("display");

// Creating Random Boxes Function
function CreateRandomBoxes() {
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  dispDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
  newDiv.className = "boxes";
  newDiv.id = "box" + num;
  num++;

  var ranWidth = Math.round(Math.random()*50)+50;
  var ranHeight = Math.round(Math.random()*50)+50 ;
  let r = Math.round(Math.random()*255),
      g = Math.round(Math.random()*255),
      b = Math.round(Math.random()*255);

  newDiv.style.width = ranWidth + "px";
  newDiv.style.height = ranHeight + "px";
  newDiv.style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
}
// Random Boxes
document.getElementById("createR").addEventListener("click",function(){
  CreateRandomBoxes();

});
// Increments 

var iw = 50;
var ih = 50;

document.getElementById("createI").addEventListener("click",function(){
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  dispDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
  newDiv.className = "boxes";

  newDiv.style.width = iw + "px";
  newDiv.style.height = ih + "px";
  iw += 5;
  ih += 5;

  if (iw > 100) {
    iw = 50;
  }

  if(ih > 100) {
    ih = 50;
  }
});

// Reset Function
document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click",function(){
    // disDiv.textContent = "";

    document.body.removeChild(dispDiv);
    dispDiv = document.createElement("div");
    dispDiv.id = "display";
    document.body.appendChild(dispDiv);
});

// Auto Creation
document.getElementById("auto").addEventListener("click",function(){
  var spd = document.getElementById("speed").value;

  setInterval(function(){
    CreateRandomBoxes();
    window.scrollTo (0,document.body.scrollHeight);
    } , spd); 
});

// Changing speed while boxes are being created
document.getElementById("speed").addEventListener("change",function(){

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.controls {
  margin:10px auto;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.controls .create,.remove {
  width:150px;
  height:50px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size:1rem;
  border-radius:50px;
  color:#333;
  border:1px solid #eee;
  margin:0 3px;
}

.boxes {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#333;
  display:inline-block;
}

input {
  width:100px;
  float:right;
  padding:10px;
  background-color:#fff;
  border:1px solid #eee;
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  font-size:1.5rem;
  color:#333;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>CRUD</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="controls" class="controls">
    <button id="createR" class="create">create random</button>
    <button id="createI" class="create">create incremental</button>
    <button id="reset" class="remove">reset</button>
    <button id="auto" class="create">auto create</button>
    <input type="number" id="speed" min="1" value="1000"/>
  </div>
  <div id="display"></div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could assign the returned value of `setInterval` to a variable, then in your change function use `clearInterval` to stop the current timed interval, and `setInterval` again to use a new time interval. http://jsfiddle.net/swk51b6q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning, you can declare this with your variables (don't know if it's necessary, but I like to check that it's actually a running timer before trying to clear it).

```
var intvl = false;
```

The first time you set the interval, assign it to the variable:

```
intvl = setInterval(function(){
  CreateRandomBoxes();
  window.scrollTo (0,document.body.scrollHeight);
} , spd);
```

Then, in your change function, call `clearInterval` first if the timer is running, then start it with the new time instead:

```
document.getElementById("speed").addEventListener("change",function(){
  if(intvl !== false) {
    clearInterval(intvl);
  }
  var spd = document.getElementById("speed").value;
  intvl = setInterval(function() {
    CreateRandomBoxes();
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  }, spd);
});
```

The Fiddle from my comment: http://jsfiddle.net/swk51b6q/

Edit: I recommend setting a minimum time limit - having a new box appear every 20ms is crazy.

Edit again: You can put the entire change function within the `if(intvl !== false)` block if you don't want changing the timer value to automatically start the timer if it wasn't started already:

```
document.getElementById("speed").addEventListener("change",function(){
  if(intvl !== false) {
    clearInterval(intvl);
    var spd = document.getElementById("speed").value;
    intvl = setInterval(function() {
      CreateRandomBoxes();
      window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    }, spd);
  }
});
```

Edit #3: http://jsfiddle.net/swk51b6q/5

Comment: Thank you so much. Please let me know if I have fully understood the concept. So making a variable called "intvl" with Boolean allows you to "reset" by using an if statement, which is if "intvl" is not equal to "false", reset (clearInterval) input value? Sorry if I sound complicated. Also How do you set a minimum time limit? I changed the min value in html but it does not stop users from typing any numbers they desire (other than showing a message asking "please select a value that is no less than the "minimum number")?

Comment: See "Edit #3" in my response for a minimum time - basically set a variable for `minSpeed` in ms (I used 500), then in the speed field's change event, check if the entered speed is less than `minSpeed`; if it is, use `minSpeed` instead and update the field to show the `minSpeed` value. As for the bool - it's not really necessary to do that way, just a personal preference - you can take out the declaration and bool assignment altogether, along with the check (http://jsfiddle.net/swk51b6q/6/). I just like to see if the timer is running before I clear it.

Comment: Sorry I was too busy checking the first link out to check Edit #3. Yeah, I realized there is no difference whether I do "true" or "false" as it produces the same result! Thank you again. You are good at explaining things in a way people like me can understand.

Comment: Oh, one more question! I realized that it won't let me reset more than once? For example, I switched from 500 to 5000 and went back to 500 and I tried 3000 but won't work.

Comment: In my most recent edit (jsfiddle rev. 5) I don't see the issue you're mentioning. When I change it to 5000 it waits 5 seconds, then adds a box, then I change it back to 500 and it adds one every 1/2 second, then changing it to 3000 adds one every 3 seconds. Not sure what's failing - maybe something available in your Dev Tools to say why? In any case, here's a jQuery version if you're familiar with jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/2z7sa9qh/.

Comment: Yeah that is weird. Maybe I was playing around too much that it caused a bug. Thank you again. I gotta start to get used to jQuery although people are saying it is dying; I feel like it is necessary to know how to read at least.